# PowerQuery - Transposing a table record

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I'm new to powerBi, did a couple online lessons but I'm struggling with this.

My company currently uses Zendesk ticket system, and I've used the export function to get all data on a XML file.

So far so good, but we use custom fields and after importing into PowerBI, the custom fields for each ticket appear as as "table" record, and I cannot do my filters correctly.

My goal is to normalize the table, having all the custom fields as columns.

This is my current status:

[image]

And below is a detailed example of my goal.

Can somebody point me a few hints on how to extract the table and transpose the records as new columns?

Just by expanding this column, it creates a lot of duplicated rows for each ticket.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add column ... custom column ... with formula

```
=Table.Skip(Table.Transpose([custom_fields]),1)
```

Then clicking the arrows at the top of the new column and expand the fields, then rename them

Sample code:

```
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(PriorStepName, "Custom", each Table.Skip(Table.Transpose([custom_fields]),1)),
// expand all column names
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Added Custom"[Custom] , each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom" , "Custom", List,List)
in #"Expanded Data"
```

Comment: Hello sir, thank you very much. It kinda worked, but the data (and the collumns) are all scrambled together, since not all tickets have all the custom fields, and they don't come on the same order and I understand this. However, on the table record, there are 2 columns, being the first the column name and the second the data. Is there a way to respect the naming from the first column? This way, I think the data will be "null" when the ticket does not have the field, but will put the correct data on the correct columns. Sorry if I don't make myself clear

Comment: I just used Table.PromoteHeaders after some research.
Also, I found out easier to edit the XML removing the  "Type" tags with came along... this way, PowerQuery does not think it's another column. Thank you again for pointing me on the right way!